# Cutting n cakes for k people with minimal waste

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

Given an array with the radii of n cakes, and an integer (k) representing how many people (or slices) you need, what is the largest area you can cut from the cakes with the least amount of waste?

Math is not my strong suit, so I'm having trouble pinpointing the algorithm I need to use in order to derive the correct area every time. I have tried sorting the radii and then dividing the largest area by 2 until it is smaller than the next area, but that does not give consistent results.

This is where I'm at:

````
  // get areas of each cake
  const pi = 3.14159265359;
  let areas = [];
  let size;

  radii.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});

  for (let i = 0; i < radii.length; i++) {
    areas.push(pi * radii[i] * radii[i]);
  }
  // divide largest in half
  for (let i = areas.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (areas[areas.length-1] / 2 < areas[i-1]) {
    }
  }
  // if that number is smaller than the next smallest cake
  // and you can get 6 equal pieces
    // size = largest cake area / 2
  // if you cannot get 6 equal pieces
    // divide the largest cake area by 4
    // check that that number can fit into the next cakes
    // until there are 6 pieces - size = largest cake / 4
};```

input: [1,1,1,2,2,3],6
Expected output: 7.0686

input: [1,5],5
Expected output: 15.7079
````

Comment: How is "waste" defined? Please define accurately what the variables are (where to cut which cake?), which number you need to minimise, and what the constraints are (each of the `k` persons gets the same amount of cake, regardless from how many pieces?).

Comment: Even if math is not your strong suit, you should have a look at [linear optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question after you've received an answer. We're not just answering this for you, it could be useful to other people too.

Comment: Btw, this is a question from the 2019 High School Programming Contest (HSPC) hosted by Cal Poly Pomona (CPP) https://www.cpp.edu/~hspc/problems/HSPC_2019_High_School_Questions.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the solution I came up for this is basically a greedy algorithm that keeps track of how many slices should be taken out of each cake then for the next tries to figure out the best cake to add a slice to.

The method I used to figure out which cake is the best is by asking the question which cake would have the largest possible slice if I have to share with the other slices? Then I would add a slice to that cake.

In addition to this we need to keep track of the minimum slice size since all slices need to be an equal size.

Anyways, here's the algorithm. Hope this helps! :)

```
function findBiggestSlice(areas){
    let index = 0
    let largestSlice = 0
    for(let i = 0; i < areas.length; i++){
        let sliceSize = areas[i].total/(areas[i].slices + 1)
        if(sliceSize > largestSlice){
            index = i
            largestSlice = sliceSize
        }
    }
    return index
}

function nCakeskSlices(radii, slices){
    // get areas of each cake
    const pi = 3.14159265359;
    let areas = [];
    let sliceSize = Infinity;

    radii.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});

    for (let i = 0; i < radii.length; i++) {
        totalArea = pi * radii[i] * radii[i];
        areas.push({
            'total': totalArea,
            'slices': 0,
        });
    }

    for(let person = 0; person < slices; person++){
        sliceCakeIndex = findBiggestSlice(areas)
        areas[sliceCakeIndex].slices += 1;
        newSliceSize = areas[sliceCakeIndex].total/(areas[sliceCakeIndex].slices)
        sliceSize = Math.min(newSliceSize, sliceSize);
    }

    return sliceSize
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the response very much.

Comment: Great answer. (I haven't been able to find an example where the optimal size is not a division of one of the cakes.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן Indeed. Imagine that you had a solution that was not a division of one of the cakes. You would have a left-over piece from each cake. So you could gradually increase the size of the pieces until one cake had no more left-over piece. That would mean that the size was a division of that cake. (Hi! Long time no see, btw.)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, everybody gets exactly one piece of cake, everybody's piece of cake has the same area, and the leftovers are to be minimized, i.e. the size of the pieces is to be maximized. So e.g. in the second example, the large cake is cut into 5 pieces, and the small cake is left over.

Sorting the cakes by size and starting by slicing the biggest cake in 1, 2, 3, ... pieces will not necessarily give the optimal result. If you had 4 cakes with radius 4 and 1 cake with radius 5 for 5 people, then the optimal solution would be to give everyone a whole cake with radius 4 or a piece of the cake with radius 5 cut down to the same size. But that slice of the larger cake would not be exactly a half, or a third, or ... of the cake.

So any of the cakes sliced into any number of pieces could determine the optimal size. To avoid checking the same solution twice, we're going to first create a set of the sizes (i.e. a list with no doubles):

```
people: 6
cakes: 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3
sizes: 1, 2, 3
```

The order in which the cakes and the sizes are listed is not important; we're going to try them all anyway. For each of these sizes, we're going to calculate the area of the cake cut into 1, 2, 3, ... n pieces, where n is the number of people (because there's no point in cutting a cake into 7 pieces for 6 people).

```
size: 1
area: 3.1416
pieces: 3.1416, 1.5708, 1.0472, 0.7854, 0.6283, 0.5236
```

```
size: 2
area: 12.5664
pieces: 12.5664, 6.2832, 4.1888, 3.1416, 2.5133, 2.0944
```

```
size: 3
area: 28.2743
pieces: 28.2743, 14.1372, 9.4248, 7.0686, 5.6549, 4.7124
```

Now, for each size of cake, we're going to iterate over the piece sizes, and check how many of these pieces we can cut from every cake. As soon as we have enough pieces for every person, we remember this piece size as the preliminary maximum size, and go to the next size of cake. When we have checked all the sizes of cakes, we will know what the optimal size is:

```
cake area:  3.1416   3.1416   3.1416   12.5664   12.5664   28.2743

 3.1416     1        1        1        3                            ->  OK

12.5664     0        0        0        1         1         2
 6.2832     0        0        0        2         2         4        ->  OK

28.2743     0        0        0        0         0         1
14.1372     0        0        0        0         0         2
 9.4248     0        0        0        1         1         3
 7.0686     0        0        0        1         1         4        ->  OK
```

So the largest piece we found that can be cut from the available cakes 6 times has an area of 7.0686.

```js
function sliceCakes(radii, people) {
    let cakeSizes = radii.map(r => r * r * Math.PI);
    let maxSize = 0;
    new Set(cakeSizes).forEach(size => {
        for (let slices = 1; slices <= people; slices++) {
            if (cakeSizes.reduce((numberOfSlices, cake) => (
                numberOfSlices + Math.floor(cake / (size / slices))
            ), 0) >= people) {
                maxSize = Math.max(maxSize, size / slices);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    return maxSize;
}

document.write(sliceCakes([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 6));
```